# Convert from JavaScript function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function and I would like to know how to make this work with jQuery.

My HTML:

```
<video id="mainVideo" width=320 height=240 autoplay>
</video>
<br/>
<video class="thumbnail" width=100 height=100>
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<video class="thumbnail" width=100 height=100>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is the function:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".videoThumbnail");
for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
    var mainVideo = document.getElementById("mainVideo");
    mainVideo.src = e.srcElement.currentSrc;
}
```

Comment: Make no edits. Your code now works with jQuery.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  know but I mean converting it to jQuery

Comment: @zerkms then what is it?

Comment: Learning jQuery can help. But I'll give you a hint. The first 4 lines would be: `$(".videoThumbnail").click(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: @Hazz , just wondering - why would you convert something you know to something you don't know? I mean, switching from javascript to jQuery for no reason?

Comment: @phillip100 I know both but can't figure out how to convert I've tried all I could do. Do I have to explain the reason why every time? Is that everybody do in stackOverflow?

Comment: No. Like I wrote -  I'm just wondering :-) I would stick with what is working for me.

Comment: @phillip100 thank you but I'm not you. I like to learn so please

Comment: @phillip100 how much time you have when somebody asks a question instead of helping, raising more questions? BASICS couldn't be answered by developers not only you but sometimes with hundreds of thousands reputations. Remember you can't blame someone for asking, blame someone who isn't asking. Well again I'm not you. Also you can check this article: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: It may not sounds like, but I'm trying to help you. Instead of: *"This is the function. Do the job for me because I don't know how"*, would be better to ask: *"please help my understand why my jQuery code not works. I want to do this -... and I've tried this - ..."*. I'd really love to help you then :-).

Comment: @phillip100 ok sorry boss you helped me a lot more than the real answer! I gave you my code and function is working. Maybe i wanted to see the other prospects of problem solving. hahaha I'm having a laugh. You should be a supervisor of this site. if yes that article is really meaningful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, in the future post your HTML code for helping us to solve the problem:

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
        $('#mainVideo').replaceWith('<video id="mainVideo" width=320 height=240 autoplay></video>');
       $('#mainVideo').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4uDB/53)

Comment: You need to include jQuery in your page.

Comment: it is included in my page

Comment: They are not images they are HTML5 videos

Answer (score 1):

The code already works with jQuery, so there is no conversion necessary to make it functional.

That said, here is a more typical way to do this with jQuery:

```
var mainVideo = $("#mainVideo");
$(".videoThumbnail").click(function() {
  mainVideo.prop("src", this.srcElement.currentSrc);
});
```